# Probability math question (independent and mutally exclusive events)

Tags: probability

[How do i solve question 8 part b I'm not sure on how to get p(c) the answer for a intersect c is 1/15 so means p(c) should be 1/3 but I'm not sure how to get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CK7m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inclusion-exclusion and the definition of independence,
$$P(A \cup C) = P(A) + P(C) - P(A \cap C) = P(A) + P(C) - P(A)P(C).$$
Rearranging yields $$P(C) = \frac{P(A \cup C) - P(A)}{1 - P(A)}.$$

Comment: sorry but where did the 1 - p(a) come from?

Comment: nvm did it on paper and figured it out simple algebra thanks man exam next week thanks for the help